# How to get the time zone abbreviation from Time.now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

Time.now.strftime('%Z') returns 'Mountain Daylight Time' for me. I'd like to get MDT.

What's the correct way to get the time zone abbreviation?

Just in case anyone suspected I was misleading them:

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.now.strftime('%Z')
=> "Mountain Daylight Time"
irb(main):002:0> Time.now.zone
=> "Mountain Daylight Time"
irb(main):003:0> Time.now.in_time_zone('Mountain Time (US & Canada)').zone
=> "MDT"
```

Comment: really?  I get `CEST` when using `Time.now.strftime('%Z')` - ie, the abbreviation and the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) say the following: 
`%Z - Abbreviated time zone name or similar information.`

Comment: Is Time#strftime monkey patched in code or one of the gems used?

Comment: Is there any way in rails to list if a particular method is "monkey-patched"?

Comment: Yes dax -- really. I know what the docs say, but if I figured maybe they were out of date since I was not getting the expected results.

Comment: fair enough...did `Time.now.zone` work, or same thing?

Comment: Same thing. :( I added some example output to my original post.

Comment: I have actually the same problem. Which system do you use? I use Win7 with ruby 1.9.3 from rubyinstaller (without rails, only ruby). If you use also Win7, you could close the question, there is a duplicat with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092281/ruby-time-zone-returns-full-form-in-windows-7

Comment: From the related SO question, the official docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Answer (score 0):

Ran a few things, I'd say try using `Time.now.zone`

```
#This is working for me, but not for you.  I'm not sure why (although others might!)
$ > Time.now.strftime('%Z')
 => "CEST"

#This gives UTC time which is useful, but not what you're after
$ > Time.zone
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00000103049918 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @current_period=nil>
$ > Time.zone.now
 => Sat, 05 Oct 2013 09:11:01 UTC +00:00
$ > Time.zone.now.zone
 => "UTC"

#This will (perhaps) return what you want.
#It's possible that you'll still just get "Mountain Daylight Time"
$ > Time.now
 => 2013-10-05 11:12:09 +0200
$ > Time.now.zone
 => "CEST"
```