# Ruby Time zone returns full form in windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, timezone, rhodes

I want to display the Timezone abbreviation. But my Ruby keeps giving me the fullform.

```
irb(main):001:0> Time.now
=> 2014-02-28 15:11:21 +0530
irb(main):002:0> Time.now.zone
=> "India Standard Time"
irb(main):003:0>
```

This was in Ruby 1.9.3p125. Tried in Ruby 2.0 as well and same results! Even `strftime("%Z")` gives full form of the time zone and not the abbreviation.

But the documentation clearly states that only the abbreviation should be returned. I am actually building a `rhodes` application on `Windows 7`

EDIT: `Time.now.strftime("%Z")` also gives full form.

Is this coz of Windows?

Comment: Cannot reproduce your result. `Time.now.zone` and `Time.now.strftime('%Z')` return the abbreviated form.

Comment: Is this specific to Windows OS? Couldn't reproduce as well.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Yes.. *I am actually building a rhodes application on Windows 7*

Comment: May be this [wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) have some informations.

Comment: @sawa as mentioned in the question, `strftime("%Z")` also does not return abbreviation

Comment: @SteveRobinson There is no difference between `'%Z'` and `"%Z"`. They are equivalent.

Comment: @sawa I know that. I misread your comment. btw, are you on windows?

Comment: Sorry guys for my unfortunate answer. I am still a bit newbie in SO (less than 1 month actively). Next time I will be more careful to answer a question.

Comment: @Rafa Do you even understand the reason for downvote? It is not because you got different result from the OP; that is what most of us are getting. It is because you used `zone` on `Time` (and `now` on it). That does not even run correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This issue does seem to be Windows specific as I was able to reproduce it myself.
Even in the documentation, it states: 
`Also, %Z is highly dependent on the operating system. For example, it may generate a non ASCII string on Japanese Windows. i.e. the result can be different to “JST”.`
I looked around and I couldn't seem to find any simple solution to this as it is so dependent on the operating system.

Comment: Thanks! This was pretty informative. So it depends on the OS! Cool :)